# Moving object by changing CSS

Tags: javascript, css, button, buttonclick

I would like to move an object by changing CSS values in JavaScript.

I want it to move left by 10 px when a button is clicked.

HTML:

```
<button id="left" onclick="goLeft()">Left</button>
<div id="gamer">BLOCK</div>
```

CSS:

```
    #gamer{

            width:100px;
            height:50px;
            text-align: center;
            position:absolute;
            left:300px;
            top:300px;
        }
```

JavaScript:

```
function goLeft(){
            var gamer = document.getElementById("gamer");
            gamer.style.left = (parseInt(gamer.style.left) - 10) + "px";

        }
```

Comment: And the problem is?

Comment: its not working...@ColinCline

Comment: In what way is it not working? is the function not getting called? is the calculation not creating a valid left value? is the element not being found? you're not being very clear.

Comment: @KevinB i suspect the calculation not creating a valid left value

Comment: What's gone on down here? `pars`

Comment: @KevinB honest mistake. fixed

Comment: Test that theory. Log the result of the calculation to your console.

Comment: @KevinB no errors in log

Comment: showing NaN @KevinB

Comment: Next step is to figure out why `parseInt(gamer.style.left)` is giving you NaN. what does `gamer.style.left` give you?

Comment: @KevinB nothing just blank

Comment: and, there's the root fo the problem. The left property of the style object is empty at first. so you'll have to detect that and handle it approprately

Comment: Defaulting it to 300 should do the trick. `gamer.style.left || 300`. note however that means if you ever change 300, that change will have to occur in two places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your javascript as below

```
<script>
    function goLeft() {
        var gamer = document.getElementById("gamer");            
        gamer.style.left = (parseInt(gamer.offsetLeft, 10) - 10) + "px";

    }
</script>
```

offsetLeft will give you the current left position.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking to use is [`window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) instead:

```
function goLeft() {
   var gamer = document.getElementById("gamer");
   var computedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(gamer);
   gamer.style.left = (parseInt(computedStyle.left, 10) - 10) + "px";
}
```

This will give you the element's current style.

Whereas if you're using `element.style` you're only going to get the element's inline style (not the inherited or external style sheet style) as outlined here in the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style.